# How to control spring @transactional Annotation precedence?

Tags: spring

The situation is that I am using Aspectj with spring aop,I define a aspect(After advice) to do some data opration for a method.And I also use the spring @transactional for the same method.
Now the question comes,how can I control the order for them to aspectj? 
(I know how to control the two aspect defined by myself ,but I have no idea if one of them is spring @transactional  )
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can define relative order of transactional aspect using `order` attribute of `<tx:annotation-driven>`, it works the same way as orders of other aspects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,it help me fix this problem .THX